# Logged into remote server with key but can't upload file with scp

Tags: ssh, login, ip, remote-access

New to Ubuntu, I logged into my institution's remote server having generated a private/public key pair. I was set up with a username after sending the administrator the public key. I should have been able to log in by using `ssh myusername@servername` but I can only log in if I replace the servername with the IP address, `ssh myusername@xxx.xx.x.xx`

Now, wanting to upload a file I tried:

```
scp ~/myfile.rds myusername@servername:/home/myusername/
```

...which got me a `Permission denied (publickey). lost connection` message. The administrator suggested trying again, replacing servername with the IP address. That makes sense, but still the same response.

My config file, saved at `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\myUbuntuUsername\.ssh` along with the two keys, reads:

```
Host servername
    HostName xxx.xx.x.xx
    Port 22
    User myusername
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

...where `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` is the path to the private key. What could I have got wrong?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to scp from your local (WSL) shell, or from the remote shell that you opened using ssh?

Comment: From the remote shell...I guess you're going to tell me that's why it's not working ;) ...in my defence, may I say that Google has been my only instructor here. Do I need to do it from my local shell?

Comment: ... yes you do, don't worry it's a common mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the username in your `ssh` and `scp` commands shouldn’t be necessary, as the value is already in your `~/.ssh/config` file. Instead, you can do this:

```
ssh servername
```

For `scp` it’s the same:

```
scp myfile.gz servername:/path/to/save
```

Alternatively, you can pass the key file to use with `-i`:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 myfile.gz user@123.123.123.123:/path/to/save
```

Comment: Thanks! - this morning I could log in with ssh servername, which I couldn't yesterday, so that's all good (if somewhat mysterious). Also, these all work:

Comment: ... scp myfile.gz user@123.123.123.123:/path/to/save  ....and... scp myfile.gz user@servername:/path/to/save (not that the extra verbiage is necessary, I was just curious)